# why is scapy module not working in pycharm community Edition 3.1.4

Tags: python

I saw a few posts about the topic but nothing worked, when I import Scapy to Pycharm community Edition 3.1.4 it doesn't work I tried it in several ways:

```
 i,o,e = sys.stdin,sys.stdout,sys.stderr
from scapy.all import *
sys.stdin,sys.stdout,sys.stderr=i,o,e

def main():
    """
    Add Documentation here
    """
    syn_segment = TCP(dport=80, seq=123, flags='S')
    syn_segment.show()
    my_packet = IP(dst='www.google.com')/syn_segment
    my_packet.show()
    send(my_packet)
    print syn_segment
```

but it didn't work:(
and when I saw in one of the answers here that was :

```
from scapy.layers.inet import *
```

it gave me back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/RT/Pycharm`enter code here`Projects/scaLY/SCAP.py", line 4, in <module>
    from scapy.layers.inet import *
  File "C:\Heights\PortableApps\PortablePython2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\scapy\layers\inet.py", line 17, in <module>
    from scapy.layers.l2 import *
  File "C:\Heights\PortableApps\PortablePython2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\scapy\layers\l2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from scapy.ansmachine import *
  File "C:\Heights\PortableApps\PortablePython2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\scapy\ansmachine.py", line 14, in <module>
    from scapy.sendrecv import send,sendp,sniff
  File "C:\Heights\PortableApps\PortablePython2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 15, in <module>
    from scapy.arch.consts import DARWIN, FREEBSD, OPENBSD
  File "C:\Heights\PortableApps\PortablePython2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\__init__.py", line 96, in <module>
    from scapy.arch.windows.compatibility import *
  File "C:\Heights\PortableApps\PortablePython2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\compatibility.py", line 172, in <module>
    scapy.sendrecv.sndrcv = sndrcv
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sendrecv'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old version of Scapy (the `compatibility.py` file was removed ages ago)

You should try to update it from within the pycharm console through a `pip install --upgrade scapy`  (or similar). Make sure you are updating the package on the Python installation you are using.

Also note that recent versions of Scapy do not modify `sys.stdout`... as they used to. That was a fix to ANSII characters not being printed on Windows, which is now being handled by IPython in a much cleaner way.